# NullPointerException when trying to access a file from a JFileBrowser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I get a `NullPointerException` every time I open the filebrowser then close it without selecting a file.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!(dndfolder.exists())) {
            new File(homefolder + "DND").mkdir();
        }
        browse = new JFileChooser(homefolder+"DND");
        returnVal = browse.showOpenDialog(loadchar);
        browse.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if(browse.getSelectedFile().exists()) {
            sheet = browse.getSelectedFile();
        }
        if(sheet.exists() && sheet.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().edit(sheet);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(panel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else {
                error = "*I don't really know what to put here";
                repaint();
            }
        } else {
            error = "*File type not supported";
                repaint();
        }
    }
```

I can open text files but it fails when selected item doesn't exist. I tried to code around it but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `I tried to code around it` And what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(browse.getSelectedFile().exists())
```

If you have not selected a file, then `browse.getSelectedFile()` probably returns `null`, but you go ahead and call `exists()` on it.

You should do something like:

```
if (browse.getSelectedFile != null && browse.getSelectedFile().exists())
```

Comment: maybe this will fix it then
if(browse.getSelectedFile() != null)

Comment: What if the user cancels from the `JFileChooser`, but for some reason a selected file is still returned... this behavior is undefined.  The result would be performing an action on a file that the user said to cancel!  It would be much better to use `JFileChooser` correctly in the first place.

Comment: well, i'm using it for the first time today. how do i say to only execute when the open button is pressed.  and jan, thanks, after i saw your first answer i made that change. i just need use the open button correctly now.